# Batch, UNC Paths, Delim _ remove trailing path

Tags: batch-file, filepath, unc

Looking for a little help, i have a text file containing UNC paths, all paths have a specific delim i can use to find where the path should end (so i can mount the parent UNC path as a drive)

Example text file

```
\\myunc.myunc.com\parent1\parent2\location_1\blah\blah\
\\myunc.myunc2.com\parent1\location_1\blah\blah\
\\myunc.myunc2.com\parent1\parent2\parent3\parent4\location_1\blah\
```

in theory i need it to parse this text file, and output the paths as

```
\\myunc.myunc.com\parent1\parent2\
\\myunc.myunc2.com\parent1\
\\myunc.myunc2.com\parent1\parent2\parent3\parent4\
```

i need to find the _ and remove the path string in front of it until \

--

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO GRABBING UNC PATHS
ECHO.
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b in (pathdumpunc.txt) do (
    SET UNCPATH=%%b
    ECHO !UNCPATH!
        for %%a in (!UNCPATH!) do set LastFolder=%%~nxa
        ECHO !LastFolder!
PAUSE
)
```

ive gone as for as identifying the last folder path name, but thats as far as ive gotten, and it seems the "LastFolder=%%~nxa" line takes forever to run , like 10+ seconds.

any help would be apprecited.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple one liner that works from the command line:

```
for /f "delims=_" %F in (pathdumpunc.txt) do @echo %~dpF
```

Double up the percents to use it in a batch file